# Machine learning algorithm for mixed categorical and numeric features

Tags: machine-learning

I have a training dataset of 1000 samples. It contains about 50 features out of which 30 are categorical features where as the rest are numerical/continuous features. Which algorithm is best suited to handle mixed feature set of both categorical and continuous features?

Answer (score 2):

In general, a preferred approach is to convert all your features into standardized continuous features.

1. For features that were originally continuous, perform standardization: x_i = (x_i - mean(x)) / standard_deviation(x). That is, for each feature, subtract the mean of the feature and then divide by the standard deviation of the feature. An alternative approach is to convert the continuous features into the range [0, 1]: x_i = (x_i - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)).
2. For categorical features, perform binarization on them so that each value is a continuous variable taking on the value of 0.0 or 1.0. For example, if you have a categorical variable "gender" that can take on values of MALE, FEMALE, and NA, create three binary binary variables IS_MALE, IS_FEMALE, and IS_NA, where each variable can be 0.0 or 1.0. You can then perform standardization as in step 1.

Now you have all your features as standardized continuous variables.

Comment: Yes, I converted all categorical features into numerical features just as you suggested, But these features can only have a value of 0 or 1 as opposed to a real numeric feature like salary whose range is large. For categorical features, may be a probabilistic algorithm like Naive Bayes is probably more accurate and for all continuous features, something like SVM might work better. But is there an algorithm that can work better for a use case that has a good mix of both categorical and continuous features? By the way this is a binary classification problem.

Comment: Convert the categorical features to be continuous/floating-point (either 0.0 or 1.0), not integer (either 0 or 1). This will allow you to perform any later computation you need in your ML algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Standardizing the categorical or discrete variables (i.e. either 0 or 1) is not a good idea, because normalized inputs will be  following an out-of-training data distribution (e.g. 0.5 or 0.7), which were never part of the input signal.